# Can I use named parameters for function CURSOR result?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, cursor

I've used the approach shown in [Returning a JDBC result set from an Oracle stored procedure](http://www.enterprisedt.com/publications/oracle/result_set.html) article.

```
String query = "{ call ? := sp_get_stocks(?) }";

CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);

stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.setFloat(2, price);

stmt.execute();

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);
while (rs.next()) {
    //...
}
```

The code did the job.

However I tend to use named parameters in my code, and wanted to change this to:

```
stmt.registerOutParameter("returnvalue", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.setFloat("p$price", price);
```

This gave me an oracle error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; The symbol "; was inserted before ">" to continue.

Is there any special convention I should use to name the function return value? Or is this even possible?

P.S.: I am actually new to java, as mainly working with .Net; so I may be missing something very basic.

---

**UPDATED**

It appeared to be that I do not get this error, when calling a more complicated function with two input parameters, one output param and the function return value itself. Named parameters in this case work well.

It seems that the problem origins from `OracleTypes.CURSOR` as the function return value...

Answer (score 1):

There is a little problem, but you can do this:

```
OracleCallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) connection
        .prepareCall("begin :a := TEST(:b); end;");

cs.setDateAtName("b", new java.sql.Date(1));
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DATE);
cs.execute();
```

The problem is:

> - If you are using `setXXX(int,...)`, `setXXXAtName(String,...)` or a combination of both, then any **output parameter** is ***bound*** with **`registerOutParameter(int,...)`** and ***not*** `registerOutParameter(String,...)`, which is for named parameter notation.

See more in [*Interface oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraint.htm#CHDBGJFG).

**UPDATE**

Check the examples (you can download the code) in the book [*Expert Oracle JDBC Programming*](http://www.apress.com/9781590594070), in the Chapter 6.

For the error, see https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2331885

Comment: +1: thank you for the link. It's really helpfull. However, you're addressing the second point of the *Note* article under the link. But it seems to me that my case should address the first one saying: *The setXXX(String,...) and registerOutParameter(String,...) methods can be used only if all binds are procedure or function parameters only. The statement can contain no other binds and the parameter binds must be indicated with a question mark (?) and not :XX.*....And according to this, I do not see any *little problem*. Am I wrong?

Comment: I mean that I use only *?* sign for parameters indication, and both parameters are set through the name (not a number). And that should be enough, as far as I understand. Or have I missed smth?

Comment: You are rigth! You can use the actual names like in your function.

Comment: But why do I get an error then? What can it be connected with?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing anything basic - as far as I know, you are stuck with numbered parameters.

You can simulate named parameters by defining some constants ( or using an enum )

```
private final static int returnvalue = 1;
private final static int p_price = 2;

......

stmt.registerOutParameter(returnvalue, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.setFloat(p_price, price);
```

But I think that's as close as you are going to get

Comment: Calling a stored procedure (not a function) with both input and output parameters **works well with parameter names**. I can't understand, why it doesn't work with parameter names when calling a function. What is the difference?